# How to check for Carriage Return of each element end in string array and add if not exists?

Tags: c#

I have a string array with string elements, here how to check each string element at the end contains carriage return(\n, \r, \n\r) and add if not contains at the end.

pls help me

Thanks

Comment: is this homework? did you write any code to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty simple to do:

```
var arr = new string[5];
for(int i =0; i< arr.Length; i++)
    if (!arr[i].EndsWith("\r") && !arr[i].EndsWith("\n"))
        arr[i] = $"{arr[i]}\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store carriage returns in an string array and check if your string ends with any of carriage return present in an carriage return array. If not then append it.

```
 using System.Linq;
 ...

var carraigeReturn = new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" };
var inputStrings = new [] {"your input strings"};

for(int i= 0; i < inputStrings.Length; i++)
{
    //Any will check any of the carriage return present in an array. 
    //If you want to check all then use .All()
    if(!carraigeReturn.Any(x => inputStrings[i].EndsWith(x))
          inputStrings[i] = $"{inputStrings[i]}\r\n";
}
```